# Cannot rotate the screen on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, display-rotation

I browsed all the answers but found nothing useful. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+arrow doesn't work. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>...doesn't work.

```
C:\Display.exe /rotate:90,
```

doesn't know how to do this? The display window doesn't have the orientation tab

Comment: Have you seen this one already: http://superuser.com/questions/495631/how-do-i-rotate-windows-8-screen ?

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Arrow only works for the old integrated Intel graphics (GMA graphics)

Comment: Yes, I read that thread, but my control panel doesn't have orientation tab!