# Windows 8.1 - How to flip the screen like Linux?

Tags: windows, windows-8, display

I am using Windows 8.1 and I need to apply Linux-like, in Windows I have only those features http://www.wikihow.com/Rotate-Your-Computer-Screen

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xrandr --output $a --reflect x
```

EDIT:

Tried https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/  but its not working without two monitor, in Linux I can use one monitor and still do the `--reflect x` and its free

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rotate Windows 8 screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/495631/how-do-i-rotate-windows-8-screen)

Comment: Please check out this question here: http://superuser.com/questions/495631/how-do-i-rotate-windows-8-screen If your question is different, please explain how.

Comment: NO NO NO NO - its not rotate. Please read it carefully its flip flip flip flip horizontally.

Comment: FLIP horizontal is not ROTATE. We use it for NEWS channels for EYE contacts. Where the desktop get totally flip horizontally and then used with Mirror. In linux we use this simply by --reflect x

Comment: Like rear-projecting an image onto a screen?

Comment: Windows doesn’t offer this. So unless your graphics driver supports it (it doesn’t), you’re out of luck. Every other solution is potentially very detrimental to performance.

Comment: Based on my google-fu, Daniel B is entirely correct. Windows does not offer this out of the box. Xsplit, the screen casting software, has been asked to support this, but it seems their solution does all the monitors as well, just like Ultramon.

Comment: Same PC, Same Hardware, when i use Linux and apply xrandr --output $a --reflect x it works. But with Windows its like impossible to find any tools

Answer (score 0):

Ultramon does do flip, albeit in software. it has flip v and flip h
if you need a webpage flipped however:

you can always f12 and:
body {
transform: scaleX(-1);
}